# How do we connect the ADT to Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

This is in Mac OS X Mavericks.

I downloaded the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.

I downloaded the ADT (Android Developer Tools) plugin from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download. Clicked on the "Get the SDK for an existing IDE" link, not the ADT + Eclipse button.

I have the PATH set up in .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Developer/android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Developer/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Developer/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools
```

Now how do I get these two products to talk to each other? There is no Window > SDK Manager, or Window > Android.

This setup is to generate Cordova PhoneGap apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Eclipse and Android SDK separately, you will download:

- Eclipse IDE
- [Android SDK for MACOS](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-macosx.zip)
- [ADT plugin for Eclipse](https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.4.zip)

Then unzip Android SDK (Android SDK require JDK).
And open Eclipse to install ADT:

- Click `Help` -> `Install New Software` -> `Add` -> Click `Archive` to ADT plugin zip file.

After that, you must restart Eclipse, Eclipse will ask you the location of Android SDK (You had unzip).
Done.

Comment: I guess I have the wrong file folder then: android-sdk-mac-x86. When I follow Help > Install New Software > Add > local, it keeps wanting a zip or jar file and I can't find one in the folder.

Comment: Help > Install New Software > Add > **Archive** not **local**. You choose the ADT zip file (ADT-23.0.4.zip).

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ You'll want to choose 32-bit or 64-bit. Don't know which? Go to http://64or32.com/
2. Download the ADT (Android Developer Tools) plugin from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download. Click on the "Get the SDK for an existing IDE" link, not the ADT + Eclipse button.
3. Let's set up the Android SDK Manager so it runs from Eclipse. Run > External Tools... > External Tools Configurations, click on the "Program" type at left, click on the left page icon for new program, click on Main tab, in Location section, click Browse File System..., choose the android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/android file. At top for Name, type Android SDK Manager. Click Apply, then Run. The SDK Manager should open.
4. To use it in Eclipse later on, click on Run > External Tools... > Android SDK Manager.